# Differentiating the term, $y=\sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1-x}}$

Tags: calculus, differential

In my calculus book, the above question was given. Since the the term can be simplified, I simplified it to $$\sqrt{(1+x)}$$ which differentiates to $$0.5\sqrt{{\frac{1}{1+x}}}$$ But the answer in the book is $$0.5\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{1-x^2}}$$  I know, if we simplify it gives the same answer.  Then why didn't the author simplify the answer? Is there any special reason?

Comment: Whoa: Isn't the derivative of $\sqrt x$ given by $\dfrac 1{2\sqrt x}$?

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Note that simplifying assumes $x$ is not equal to 1. Otherwise you can't cancel $(x-1)$. It is worth checking what problems does simplifying get you into - I don't know.

Comment: the domain of the function doesn't include 1. since the domain = {x: x<}.  So, I cancelled the terms.

Comment: sorry, some one edited the answer. (Last term)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint What if $x=1$ would you do like $\frac{0\times 2}{0}$ and then cancel $0$ .There are indeterminate forms so its safe to keep it like that. Hint you can also make that function continuous by removing singularity at $x=1$ ie(removal of discontinuity at $1$).

Comment: It is in fact safe to keep it like that.

Comment: but x is not equal to 1,since it produces an error.

Comment: I'm sure this was clear in your mind when you wrote it,  but in the light of the following day it stands in need of revision.  The run-on sentences should be corrected, and the "hint" should be tied to the Question with a bit more clarity (removing the removable discontinuity is close to circular reasoning).

Comment: @hardmath more clarity needed

Comment: If it were my Answer, I would replace the "hints" with declarative sentences that refer to the specific function $y = \sqrt{\frac{1-x^2}{1-x}}$.  The OP already noted a simplification when $x\neq 1$ (and $x \ge -1$, although this restriction was not noted), so being more explicit about the consequences of simplification is cogent.  ("Then why didn't the author simplify the answer? Is there any special reason?")

Answer (score -1):

Ted's comment is in fact the answer: you didn't differentiate $\sqrt{x}$ correctly. You made it $\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{x}$; it is in fact $\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{x}}$.

Although actually the answer in the book is also incorrect. The author should probably have simplified an expression of the form $\frac{1-x^2}{1-x}$, since the singularity at $x=1$ is removable.

Comment: sorry. it was a typing mistake